A measure of reflexivity of Banach spaces with bases
R. C. James proved that a Banach space $X$ with a basis $(x_{n})_{n}$ is reflexive if and only if $(x_{n})_{n}$ is both shrinking and boundedly complete. In 1968, M. Zippin proved that a Banach space $X$ with bases is reflexive if and only if all bases of $X$ are shrinking if and only if all bases of $X$ are boundedly complete.
Let $(z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a (norm) bounded sequence in a Banach space $X$. We set $$\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=\inf_{n}\sup_{k,l\geq n}\|z_{k}-z_{l}\|.$$ Then $(z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is norm-Cauchy if and only if $\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=0$.
Let $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a basis for a Banach space $X$. We set $$\textrm{bc}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=\sup\Big\{\textrm{ca}((\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i})_{n=1}^{\infty})\colon
\sup_{n}\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}\|\leq 1\Big\}.$$ Clearly, $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is boundedly complete if and only if $\textrm{bc}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=0$.
Let $X$ be a Banach space with bases. We set $$\textrm{bc}(X)=\sup_{(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\in \mathcal{B}(X)}\textrm{bc}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})(\leq 2),$$ where $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the family of all bases of $X$. Then a Banach space $X$ with bases is reflexive if and only if $\textrm{bc}(X)=0$.  We have proved that if $X$ is non-reflexive, then $\textrm{bc}(X)\geq 1.$ Furthermore, we have proved that $$\textrm{bc}(c_{0})=\textrm{bc}(L_{1}[0,1])=\textrm{bc}(C[0,1])=\textrm{bc}(\ell_{1})=2.$$
Question. Is $\textrm{bc}(X)=2$ for every non-reflexive Banach space ?
Thank you.

What is ca$((\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_ix_i)_{n=1}^\infty)$?

I add the definition of  $\textrm{ca}$.
